# QProcess::startDetached() hangs out when executing google-chrome

Tags: qt, google-chrome, centos7, qprocess, qtwebengine

The issue is present only on CentOS 7, using Qt 5.12.6

In the Qt application we open a configuration tool using the following command:

```
QProcess::startDetached("google-chrome", {"http://localhost:8080/"});
```

For some strange reason, the exit the application is not completed (the last `return exitCode` in main() is executed) and only when Chrome's window is closed, the application process finishes.

Here is what I see after quit the application (the GUI was closed):

```
$ pstree -p 26609
Application(26609)─┬─QtWebEngineProc(26702)
                   ├─{Application}(26652)
                   ├─{Application}(26653)
                   ├─...
```

For some reason, the **QtWebEngineProc** remains running associated to the Application.

```
$ cat /proc/26702/status 
Name:   QtWebEngineProc
Umask:  0002
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   26702
Ngid:   0
Pid:    26702
PPid:   26609
TracerPid:  0
Uid:    2000    2000    2000    2000
Gid:    2000    2000    2000    2000
FDSize: 1024
Groups: 10 977 978 979 2000 
VmPeak:   436736 kB
VmSize:   436732 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmPin:         0 kB
VmHWM:     23172 kB
VmRSS:     23172 kB
RssAnon:        5580 kB
RssFile:       17592 kB
RssShmem:          0 kB
VmData:     2092 kB
VmStk:       132 kB
VmExe:         4 kB
VmLib:    153160 kB
VmPTE:       484 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:    1
SigQ:   1/62901
SigPnd: 0000000000000000
ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
SigBlk: 0000000000000000
SigIgn: 0000000000000002
SigCgt: 0000000180010000
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 0000001fffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
NoNewPrivs: 1
Seccomp:    0
Speculation_Store_Bypass:   thread vulnerable
Cpus_allowed:   fff
Cpus_allowed_list:  0-11
Mems_allowed:   00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
Mems_allowed_list:  0
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    109
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 2
```

Do you know what could be happening with QtWebEngine that stays attached to my main process?

Do you have some trick to mimic `gio open` using a bash script without making my hard-coded gio version in C?

**Note 1**: The usage `xdg-open` or `gio open` does not hangs the exit of the main application's process, but I cannot use it because I need to open Chrome and not the default browser.

```
QProcess::startDetached("xdg-open", {"http://localhost:8080/"});
```

**Note 2**: the same Application in RockyLinux 9.3 does not have this behavior, it works.

**Note 3**: The usage `system()` did not work

```
system("bash -c \"google-chrome http://localhost:8080/\" &");
```